# Help need making decision. Ads rotating site on wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, custom-taxonomy

Okey guys, I am little confused here. I am building a ads rotating site (specifically for jpgs/gif banners) for my client where people can add banners and create code to put in there site.

**My Plan So Far:**

1. Individual Ads will be a custom post type.
2. Each ads will have a specific banner size.
3. Ads Group: A group of ads where couple of same size ads can be added. The rotating code will be associated with the group not a single ads.

So you see the **Ads Group** will be something that will contain the post id of the ads that associated in that group. Also i need to validate the banner size of the group (two different banner size can't be in a same group).

**Now what I am confused about is** should i use custom post type for groups too? or i should use only taxonomy? Custom post type looks too bigger for the purpose because I only need to save the Group Ads size (125x125, 468x60 etc) and the post ids in a group item. And when i think of using taxonomy it is easy to use store the post ids (wordpress will handle that!) but how come I save the Group ads size? Is it possible to add meta values for taxonomy items?

I hope you get my whole idea? Let me know if you are not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meta for taxononmies is not available out of the box, you need to create separate database table for [Metadata API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Metadata_API) to work.

If size is the **only** extra data you need and that is not going to change I'd try to use term description to hold it.

Otherwise you are better off with CPT or something custom and simple.

Comment: I need couple of info to store actually. Size, Post_ids and numbers of ads. I will check metadata api. Also thinking for making a separate post type for it. Not sure if that would be a good idea or not.

Comment: @Sisir using taxonomy gets you IDs of post in for term and total number per term easily. It's ad size that doesn't fit in native schema. But as per my answer this would be easy to achieve hack for single item of extra data. For more you will need either to use CPT or build out on top of taxonomy.

Comment: Thanks! I think i will go with CPT. This will help to add more feature in future.